# DownloadManager makes multiple of the same download on connecting to internet again

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have a data source of map points that aught to be updated from time to time when online. Unfortunately it seems to go and download this one url multiple times when I finally get my Android device back to Wifi. Is there a more appropriate use to do this or cancel and recreate this download from time to time?

```
@Override
protected void  onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://url"));
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"filename");
    downloadJSONReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WorkManager` instead:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Although you need to write download logic, I believe WorkManager better fits your needs.

Comment: That's good, but I only need the download to happen once in awhile if the user uses the app. So when app is in foreground/resume, makes sense.